# replace all null values with 0 across 100+ columns without having to specify the column names

Tags: sql-server

I have created a pivot table in SQL server ready to export in to Stata.

The data has 151 columns, the first being a unique person identifier, the rest are dummy variables that should take on the value of 1 or 0.

However, I am trying to find a way to either amend the pivot syntax to replace null with zero or change each column in the pivot table so that the null is zero. There are other tables that i will need to create and they will have different names for the 150 dummies - so would like to find a way to do this without having to specify each of the column names.

Comment: `ISNULL({expression},0)` (or `COALESCE`)?

Comment: You can create a dummy intersections with a zero value from your base data which will eliminate nulls, but without sample data it is hard to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

I have never found a scenario where it can be done inside a query, unless you use dynamic SQL.

For static queries I use the below two methods:

1. SSMS supports regular expressions [search and replace](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/regex-based-finding-and-replacing-of-text-in-ssms/).

   You can craft a RegEx that will replace all 150 columns with ISNULL( [columnName], 0 ) AS [columnName]. RegEx syntax is the same as .Net RegEx

   If you save you RegEx, you can re-use it for another table.
2. Use Microsoft Excel (or similar spreadsheet software) string manipulation functions to generate your new column list. This is extremely useful if you are a given a column list and need to create a table with a lot of columns of the same type.